# How to download images to local folder when they are linked to the internet in Markdown

Tags: xml, wordpress, markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am now moving my web from Wordpress to Hugo, just to be able to write posts using RMarkdown through the package `blogdown`.

I followed the steps described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/from-wordpress.html). So far, I succeded. However, I found one unexpected problem.

When the XML obtained from the WP export is converted using `exitwp`, images in the original posts are linked to their internet URLs, so that they are not downloaded in the local machine and linked accordingly in the `.Rmd` files.

This is an example.

[image]

So my question is, how can I download all the linked images into my local R Project, so that later on I can serve my site and convert it to Hugo using `blogdown`?

The issue is that I will completely remove the WP website and substitute with the Hugo one.

Comment: Hi, working on the same question. There are probably more tools in JS than in R for instance. I haven't found a working library yet, but since it's a limited use case, a regex on `![.*](.*)` should work => the second part would be the absolute URL. That's the hard part, then it's easier to download the file + do a string replacement of the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this somehow automatically? I don't think blogdown has a feature like that. If you have many images, you could: make a r script for going through the Rmd files, getting the images with `httr` and placing them in the corresponding folder.